# how to do 'converge' style functional programming in R?

Tags: r

guys:

I have a list of binary rdata files. say

```
filenames<-c(f1,f2,f3 .... etc)
```

and I have a loadBinFile(fname) function which reads binary file and return a data frame. Then, how can I write a functional programming style 'coverge' that goes through the filenames list and increamentally builds an aggregated big data frame?

in kdb, it's something like

```
(),/loadFile[]  each filenames
```

any R equivalent?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
do.call("rbind", lapply(filenames, loadFile))
```

It might be that this works but it depends on the content:

```
sapply(filenames, loadFile)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I think you want `rbind`.

```
big.df <- rbind(df1, df2, df3... dfn)
```

This will return a matrix but you can coerce with `as.data.frame`.  Watch out too for column names, if those are important.